# AngularJS and Bootstrap 3: Modal won't open a second time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a weird problem where on the second attempt to open a modal, and I think it has to do with not being able to close properly. I'm very much an angular n00b, so I'm not really sure I'm doing something obviously wrong. The modal opens the first time, and if I cancel, it will open again (and never error that way). When I submit, it will work the first time, and pass the data along to other functions, however if I try to open the modal a second time, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: v2.addCounter is not a function
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:13567:15), <anonymous>:4:364)
at callback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:23934:17)
at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:16251:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:16351:25)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js:23939:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.m.event.dispatch (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3:8549)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3:5252)
```

I'm using angularJS (1.4.9), bootstrap (tpls-1.1.1) and jquery (jquery-1.3.2).

Here's a skeleton of my modal.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="addcounter.html">   
<ng-form name="vm.addCounterForm">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Add Counter</h3>
    </div>
    <button type="button" style="btn" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <span ng-show="materialDistributor && materialManufacturer && materialColourGroup && materialDescription">
        <button type="button" style="btn" ng-click="vm.saveCounterModal(A bunch of ng-model stuff being sent)">Save Counter
        </button>
    </span>
</ng-form>
```

I'm going to leave my unedited modal stuff in my angular controller file:

```
//baby's first modal
    vm.addCounter = function (groupIndex, size) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: true,
          templateUrl: 'addcounter.html',
          controller: ['$uibModalInstance', 'materials', 'groupIndex', addTableCtrl],
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            materials: function() {return vm.materials},
            groupIndex: function() {return groupIndex}
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (counter) {
            //console.log(counter.width, counter.length, counter.shape, counter.material, counter.index);
            vm.saveCounter(counter.width, counter.length, counter.shape, counter.material, counter.index, counter.groupIndex, counter.description);
        }, function () {
        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    var addTableCtrl = function($uibModalInstance, materials, groupIndex) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.materials = materials;
        vm.groupIndex = groupIndex;
        vm.saveCounterModal = function(width, length, shape, material, index, description) {
            var counter = {
                width: width,
                length: length, 
                shape: shape, 
                material: material,
                index: index,
                groupIndex: groupIndex,
                description: description
            };

            $uibModalInstance.close(counter);
        };

        vm.cancel = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
```

Am I right in thinking that the close function isn't working properly? As the comments say, this is baby's first modal :(

**SOLUTION**

The "save" button I had a function that was no longer being used. Instead of erroring at the line the function was being called at, the whole modal was showing as the cause of the error. Hope this helps other people having this issue!

Comment: what is the vm? can you put more code here or create a plunker?

Comment: Do you see `Modal dismissed at: [date]` in the console when you dismiss or close it??

Comment: @BrianBaker, I can see the "modal dismissed at" message. And I can close it as many times as I want, by clicking cancel. It also closes when I click where the modal isn't.

Sadfacre, vm is set to 'this'. I started coding using $scope, but in an example for something else I was doing, it was recommended to us "this" and to tie it to a variable to make it easier. Apparently it's 'tidier', but as a n00b, I'm not sure if that's the case. I'd have to change my entire app to change things back to $scope, though.

I will put up a plunkr asap.

Comment: When you didn't have the `//console.log(counter.width, counter.length, counter.shape, counter.material, counter.index);` line edited out what was the result?

Comment: @BrianBaker All those variables would be filled and show the correct numbers/strings. I used that to make sure I was passing the right variables, and commented it out once I got the variables sending through properly.

Comment: I was just making sure that the close() function got fired. Why does the error say v2.addCounter? Shouldn't it be vm.addCounter?

Comment: @BrianBaker, I was confused by the at first myself, but I noticed that the error is coming directly from the angular js file, not from my written code.

Edit: yeah, the close command definitely fires :)

Comment: You should include the rest of your HTML.

Comment: @BrianBaker, all my code is [here](https://github.com/shhtephe/SurfacingSolutions), please let me know if that helps. I'm trying to take the code apart and put it in a plunkr, but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: So I figured out the issue: 

The "save" button I had a function that was no longer being used. It still seems weird to me that it didn't error out the first time!

Answer (score 0):

So the code below is called when you hit the 'save' button which closes the modal and runs a function.

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (counter) {
        vm.saveCounter(counter.width, counter.length, counter.shape, counter.material, counter.index, counter.groupIndex, counter.description);
    }, function () {
    console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

In the called function (vm.savecounter) there was a function within it which called another function (vm.hideCounter - shown below), which I forgot to remove. This function basically cleared some dropdowns and text boxes, which were now in the modal.

```
//Basically none of these things are in the DOM since I moved them to the modal.
        vm.hideCounter = function() {  
             vm.addCounter = false;
             vm.shape = "",
             vm.counterWidth = "",
             vm.counterLength = "",
             vm.materialColourGroup = "",
             vm.materialDistributor = "", 
             vm.materialManufacturer = "",
             vm.materialColourGroup = "";
         };
```

So basically (this is my interpretation), they were trying to manipulate things that were in the modal and not part of the main page. It's still really weird to me that the manipulation attempt (clearing a textbox that was no longer there) only gave an error on the second attempt.

Does this sound like it might be a bug and should probably error out on the first try?